# solving this linear equation by substitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Here's what I was given:**

$\frac{x}{2}$ + $\frac{y}{3}$ = 6

3$x$ - 2$y$ = 12

I isolated $x$ in the second equation and got:

$x$ = 4  + $\frac{2}{3}$$y$

I substituted $x$ for 4  + $\frac{2}{3}$$y$ in the first equation:

$\frac{(4  + \frac{2}{3}y)}{6}$ + $\frac{y}{2}$ = 2

$y$ = $\frac{32}{33}$

**correct answer:** 6

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed your wrong substitution of x in the first equation, I will recommend doing something else.

I will recommend simplifying the 1st equation into a simple "integer" equation to eliminate wrong substitution and any confusions.
$${x\over 2}+{y\over 3}=6$$ 
$${3x+2y\over 6}=6$$
$${3x+2y}=36$$ 
Adding both equations: $$(3x+2y)+(3x-2y)=12+36)$$
we obtain:  $$6x=48, or, x=8 $$

plugging it back into any equation to get:
$$y={36-2(8)\over 2}=6.$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a start, if $x=4+\frac{2}{3}y$, then $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{3}=6$ becomes $\frac{4+\frac{2}{3}y}{2}+\frac{y}{3}=6$, not $\frac{4+\frac{2}{3}y}{6}+\frac{y}{2}=2$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\frac{(4  + \frac{2}{3}y)}{6}+\frac{y}{2}=2$ is wrong !

Correct is: $\frac{(4  + \frac{2}{3}y)}{6}+\frac{y}{9}=2$